# How to pull google spreadsheet data into a svg map made with raphael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, google-sheets, raphael

I have an svg map made using raphaeljs. How can i pull data from the following spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rIzLXVN0vyCd66ryLD7z7ktw242ygnl4-ksuqVz01X0/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

I need to display the data from the spreadsheet like the region and population in the h3 and p tags i have below the actual map div. i have included the jsfiddle link below to get an idea.

`<body>
     <div id="map" class="tamilnadu"></div>
     <h3 id="region-name"></h3>
     <p id="pop-num"></p>
</body>`

http://jsfiddle.net/diviseed/6ts8wcgj/

Any help would be appreciated